# Generating a Notification at specific date and time

Tags: android, android-notifications, alarmmanager

I am trying to create a to-do application where user can set date and time for their tasks. Once user has define his task and has exit the application, user should get the notification from the app about the task that he has defined in the application. Below is the snippet that I've tried.

**todocreate.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_todo_create);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("ToDoList Create");

        myToDoHelper = new myDBHelper(todo_create.this);


        titleText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getTitle);
        dateText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getDate);
        timeText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getTime);

        pickDate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pickDate);
        pickTime = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pickTime);

        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        pickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(todo_create.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                        dateText.setText(dayOfMonth +"-"+(month+1)+"-"+year);
                        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dayOfMonth);
                        c.set(Calendar.MONTH,month+1);
                        c.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

        pickTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(todo_create.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        timeText.setText(hourOfDay +":"+minute);
                        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hourOfDay);
                        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
                        c.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
                        c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
                    }
                }, mHour, mMinute, false);
                timePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    //function to save todo task with alarm manager
    public void saveToDo(String todoTaskInput, String todoDateInput, String todoTimeInput){
        //createNotification(todoTaskInput);
        boolean isInserted = myToDoHelper.createToDo(todoTaskInput, todoDateInput,todoTimeInput);
        if(isInserted == true){
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent alarmShowIntent = new Intent(this, BroadcastReceiver.class);
            alarmShowIntent.putExtra("TodoTitle",todoTaskInput);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,alarmShowIntent,0);
            Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            long currentTime = c1.getTimeInMillis();
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,c.getTimeInMillis()-currentTime,pendingIntent);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ToDo Item created successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error occured ! Please try again after sometime",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        this.finish();
    }
```

**BroadcastManager.java**

```
package com.example.mytodoapp;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

import java.io.Console;

public class BroadcastManager extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        createNotification(context,intent,"myToDo App",intent.getStringExtra("TodoTitle"));
    }

    public void createNotification(Context context,Intent intent,CharSequence ticker, CharSequence title){
        //Intent intent = new Intent(this,todo_home.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent,0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"todoAppChannel");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_note_add_black_24dp);
        builder.setContentTitle("todo App");
        builder.setContentText(title);
        builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(200,builder.build());
    }
}
```

**home.java**
Created following method to create notification channel on application load.

```
public void createNotificationChannel(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            CharSequence name = "todoAppChannel";
            String description = "temp";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("todoAppChannel",name,importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**
Following line updated in the file.

```
<receiver android:name=".BroadcastManager"/>
```

I was able to generate the notification on button click but not on specific date on a specific time. However I am not able to generate notification for a specific date at specific time. What could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add intent filters to your receiver (correct me if I'm wrong).

```
 <receiver
     android:name="BroadcastManager">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="ALARM" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Also add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Comment: I tried adding your above snippet, but it didn't worked. Is my other logic implemented correct ?

Comment: Your logic looks perfect!